# classcastexception connecting to MySQL

Tags: eclipselink

I'm making a project to college using JSF. I'm trying to write some info on MySQL, but I got that error message:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long Error Code: 0

I've already search for solutions and I found a lot with this error, but none of then worked for me.
This error happend on:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("RestManagerPU");
```

I'm using MySQL 8.0 and Connector/J 8.0.12.

Update

Here is my persistence.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="RestManagerPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:app/RestManager</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And here is my DAOHelper, where the error occur:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package DAO;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

/**
 *
 * @author leand
 */
public class DAOHelper {
    public EntityManager getEM(){
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("RestManagerPU");
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

Stack Trace

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
Error Code: 0
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:188)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at DAO.DAOHelper.getEM(DAOHelper.java:18)
    at DAO.GenericDAO.salvar(GenericDAO.java:19)
    at BR.UsuariosBR.cadastrar(UsuariosBR.java:29)
    at Beans.UsuarioBean.cadastrar(UsuarioBean.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:750)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:731)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:135)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:196)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:114)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:103)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.addResource(ConnectionPool.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResourceAndAddToPool(ConnectionPool.java:1512)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResources(ConnectionPool.java:944)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.initPool(ConnectionPool.java:230)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.internalGetResource(ConnectionPool.java:511)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResource(ConnectionPool.java:381)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResourceFromPool(PoolManagerImpl.java:245)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:170)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:307)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResource(ConnectionPool.java:1189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:98)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:110)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:907)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:129)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:87)
    ... 83 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.buildCollationMapping(ConnectionImpl.java:1062)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3556)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:443)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:141)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:111)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:115)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.buildCollationMapping(ConnectionImpl.java:1007)
    ... 100 more
```

My database is running localhost, a MySQL 8.0. I'm using Connector/J 8.0.12.

Comment: I think you need to show us the code that's failing, otherwise we can only speculate as to what's wrong. Based on the error message, I'd take a look at anything of type `BigInteger` to start with.

Comment: Ok, I will update my question with the code

Comment: Show the stack trace and the driver versions involved.  "Error in allocating a connection" indicates it is a problem with getting a connection from your datasource, not a necessarily an issue with the application code.  How/where is the RestManager datasource configured?

Comment: @Chris I updated the question

Comment: The exception stack indicates this has nothing to do with EclipseLink or your persistence settings. It is entirely within the datasource code: com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.buildCollationMapping.  Check your datasource setup and driver version.  Quick google check for the method and error show it is a driver class issues: https://coderanch.com/t/674877/databases/error-connect-mysql-database

Comment: But I don't know what to do. I've already changed the driver, the MySQL config is all right. Actually, the connection works. I can consult with SQL and JPQL, but that error happens only when I tested the page

Answer (score 0):

I've finally find out the solution. For some reason the JDBC driver doesn't work with MySQL 8, even the driver 8.0.12. I installed MySQL 5.7 and made the connection with driver 5.1.47. Now it works.